# What is the minimum chrome version required for chrome.extension.sendMessage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried using chrome.extension.sendMessage in my extension and upset a lot of users who weren't on the same Chrome version as me (v20.0.1132.47). I tried looking at the documentation here - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage but there is nothing indicating when this method was introduced.

Compare this to the isAllowedIncognitoAccess method which *clearly* states "This function was added in version 12.0.706.0. If you require this function, the manifest key minimum_chrome_version can ensure that your extension won't be run in an earlier browser version."

Does anyone know what the minimum Chrome version is to use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `chrome.extension.sendMessage` is present in [20.0.1130.1](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php?old_chrome=7648).
- But not in [`19.0.1084.56`](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php?old_chrome=7794)

[`c.e.sendMessage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) and [`c.e.onMessage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) is introduced in Chrome 20. Before the update, `c.e.sendRequest` and `c.e.onRequest` had to be used. `c.e.sendRequest` takes the same arguments as `sendMessage`, but `onRequest` is slightly different.

```
// Chrome 20+
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(details) {
    var message = details.message;           // Any (string, object, ...)
    var sender = details.sender;             // MessageSender type
    var sendResponse = details.sendResponse; // Function
});
// Chrome 19-
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // message, sender and sendResponse defined in the parameters
});
```