# Chrome API: What Happened to `chrome(.experimental).sockets`

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

There's [documentation about `chrome.sockets`](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/socket.html) on http://developer.chrome.com/ , but I can't find anything concerning `chrome.experimental.sockets` on http://code.google.com/ any more. Dear Chromium developers, please tell me: What happened? Thanks. (I don't want to miss this wonderful API.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The [Socket API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) is only available to [Packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)** <sup>([source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161964/socket-is-not-allowed-for-specified-package-type-theme-app-etc/12163180#12163180)</sup>. This is the reason why the API is listed at the [`/apps/` API index](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html), but not [`/extensions/`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html).

If you try to use the API in an ordinary extension, the extension will fail to load, or be loaded with the following message:
[image: There were warnings when trying to install this extension: 'socket' is not allowed for specified package type (theme, app, etc.).]

Comment: @OP You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453108/where-can-i-see-which-chrome-extensions-api-is-valid-for-which-chrome-version/11454451#11454451, specifically http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/docs/how-docs-are-served.

Comment: I can see `chrome.socket` there. But it's not listed on [trunk's API index](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/api_index.html). Any idea?

Comment: @fridojet Don't worry about that. The documentation is auto-generated, but some pages have to be edited manually, [including `api_index.html`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/extensions/api_index.html?view=log).

Comment: Everything's fine as long as this API doesn't get removed.

Comment: @fridojet Considering that the API passed the experimental stage ("`chrome.experimental.socket`" -> "`chrome.socket`"), it's likely that the API stays.

Comment: @fridojet I revised my answer, FYI.