# Developer documentation for previous releases of the Chromium\Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I see which chrome extensions API is valid for which chrome version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453108/where-can-i-see-which-chrome-extensions-api-is-valid-for-which-chrome-version)

Is the any developer documentation available for previous releases of the Google Chrome\Chromium?
I need to make my extension to be backward compatible down to the Chromium 17 release, but I have no idea how to do this without documentation.

I'm looking for something like this, but for previous releases:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/docs.html#versions

Comment: TL;DR, see http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/docs/how-docs-are-served

Comment: @RobW, thank you very much. The question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: If you're using background pages, you need two separate extensions: The implementation of background pages changed radically in Chrome 18. I suggest to drop Chrome 17 support, and support Chrome 18+. Ubuntu users are still stuck at Chromium 18, so this requirement is realistic.

Comment: Yes, I'm actively using background pages, and it seems to be a problem with Chrome 17. If I understand correctly, in Chrome 17 `background.html` file should exist in the extension as a static file. In my case it's generated automatically.

Comment: Chrome 17- uses `"background_page":"background.html"`. Chrome 18+ plus manifest version 2 requires `"background": {"scripts":["background.js"]}`. (or `"background":{"page":"background.html"}`. When using a HTML page, you still need to put the JS in an external file, because of the Content security policy.

Comment: I'm currently actively negotiating with customers possibility of upgrade from Chromium17 :)