# Chrome extension sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

The documentation here seems terrible: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

I want my content script, simply to show a pageIcon if there is a textarea on the page.

My content.js (using jquery) does this:

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Then my background.js has this:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    } 
});
```

Which should be incredibly simple. If there's a textarea, show the icon.

I have tried all kinds of variations from sample code and nothing works. All I ever get is:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

in the console.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The documentation for Chrome extensions is generally excellent. You did not properly read the documentation: Event listeners to [`chrome.extension.onmessage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) receive only one parameter: The object containing `request`, `sender`, `sendResponse`. (since Chrome 20, [`onRequest` and `sendRequest` have been replaced with `onMessage` and `sendMessage`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11412113)). This is probably not the cause of the error though. Are you sure that the `onMessage` event listener is attached (ie no error occurred)?

Comment: Change onMessage to onRequest and try again, if error persists then you have to look at console log of background script (in Extensions -> Inspect Views: *** there should be your script, jusc lick and go to console,  look at error message)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have an extra curly bracket in the background script.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    } 
});
```

should be

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    } 
);
```

Comment: I'm calling sendResponse(from extension) back to send some content but not getting called.Please help.